# Verification of image accepting invalid files upload

Tags: php, mysql, upload, verification

I have a problem with my upload code it accepts invalid files and saves the filename in the database. I don't know what part of the code is wrong.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
}
?>

<?php
$allowedExts = array(
    "gif",
    "jpeg",
    "jpg",
    "png"
);
$temp        = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension   = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            $image = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $image = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
} else if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] == null) {
    $image = $_SESSION['IMAGE'];
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>

<?php
include("includes/dbConnect.php");

$Department   = $_SESSION['DEPARTMENT'];
$lname        = $_POST['lname'];
$fname        = $_POST['fname'];
$mname        = $_POST['mname'];
$alias        = $_POST['alias'];
$place        = $_POST['place'];
$address      = $_POST['address'];
$gender       = $_POST['gender'];
$nationality  = $_POST['nationality'];
$age          = $_POST['age'];
$complexion   = $_POST['complexion'];
$height       = $_POST['height'];
$weight       = $_POST['weight'];
$build        = $_POST['build'];
$haircolor    = $_POST['haircolor'];
$pecularities = $_POST['pecularities'];
$other        = $_POST['other'];
$clname       = $_POST['clname'];
$cfname       = $_POST['cfname'];
$cmname       = $_POST['cmname'];
$cnumber      = $_POST['cnumber'];
$caddress     = $_POST['caddress'];
$relationship = $_POST['relationship'];
$description  = $_POST['description'];
$lastseen     = $_POST['lastseen'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `persons`(LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,Image,Alias,Place,Address,Gender,Nationality,Age,Complexion,Height,Weight,Build,HairColor,          Pecularities, Other, CLastName, CFirstName, CMiddleName, ContactNumber, Relationship, Status, CAddress,Description,Department,lastseen) VALUES ('$lname','$fname','$mname','$image','$alias',       '$place','$address','$gender','$nationality','$age','$complexion','$height','$weight','$build','$haircolor','$pecularities',        '$other','$clname','$cfname','$cmname','$cnumber','$relationship','Missing','$caddress','$description','$Department','$lastseen')");

header('location:admin_search.php');
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

The code above verifies the user input but it also saves invalid file the file name only not the file itself. I don't know what part has the error it execute the query part but the verification for upload image accepts different file type but I have extension allowExts.

Comment: I would recommend to convert '$extension' into lower case in 'in_array()' if you want 'myPic.JPG' also as a valid file.

Comment: it's working the problem is if i put the querry it execute it even if it's invalid it saves the file name but not the file . my save path is in my directory @ViPiN

Comment: You need to put your query inside you if/else statement, otherwise it will get executed no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `exit` as the code below.

```
else {
    echo "Invalid file";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: still having an error it says invalid files when i remove the lower querry part but when i put it again it executes and saves it and won't say invalid file inside the form @DevZer0

Comment: Why not just do it in one line `die("Invalid file");`

Comment: @Fred that's one option. i am not sure if headers get sent in case of `die()` though

Comment: @DevZer0 Doesn't matter either way, the OP is using `echo` anyway, so that would fail if headers were sent.

Comment: @DevZer0 Personally, I think the OP will have to re-think this one through, find another upload snippet and apply conditions from there.

Comment: @Fred like your clipart programming style :)

Comment: @DevZer0 Exactly ;-) works for me though :) I can hard-code/debug to a pretty good extent.